# Where can I find a three block?

Tags: session

I would like to get some tricks down a three block, but haven't been able to find one yet.

Where can I find a three block in Session? I don't mind which map

I am looking for a feature which looks like this

[image: Picture of a three block]

Comment: Please mention the game name in the question and/or body rather than just the tag.

Comment: That isn't actually the case. You can read the meta discussion about it. https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13581/why-are-my-questions-having-the-game-name-added-to-the-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only one I've managed to find has a bench across the top, but you can place a kicker behind that.

It's in front of this red brick building with a white flag pole out the front.

[image: Game screenshot showing partial three block and white flag pole]